# Using enums in a class as a parameter

Tags: ios, swift, enums

Basically I have a DataManager singleton as follows:

```
class DataManager {    
    static let shared = DataManager()

    private init() {}

    static func set(_ object: String, forKey defaultName: String) {
        let defaults: UserDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
        defaults.set(object, forKey:defaultName)
        defaults.synchronize()
    }

    static func object(forKey key: String) -> String {
        let defaults: UserDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
        return defaults.object(forKey: key) as! String
    }
}
```

What I want to achieve it as follows, when setting or retrieving saved objects:

```
DataManager.set("some hash", forKey: .hash)
```

instead of:

```
DataManager.set("some hash", forKey: "hash")
```

Also, what's the technical term for the functionality I'm looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have an enum, simply DefaultKey

```
enum DefaultKey: String {
  case hash = "hash"
  case secondKey = "secondKey"
  case thirdKey = "thirdKey"
}
```

Now what you have to do is

```
static func set(_ object: String, forKey keyType: DefaultKey) {
  let defaults: UserDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
  let key = keyType.rawValue // rawvalue for keyType .hash will actually return you "hash".
  defaults.set(object, forKey: key)
  defaults.synchronize()
}
```

Now you will be able to call function like

`DataManager.set("some hash", forKey: .hash)`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use enums, for example:

```
enum DataManagerKey: String {
   case hash
}
```

and then use it in set method:

```
static func set(_ object: String, forKey defaultName: DataManagerKey)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply achieve it by implementing an enum and let `defaultName` parameter data type to be of the implemented enum, as follows:

```
enum DataManagerDefaultName: String {
    case hash
    // other cases goes here
}
```

Usage:

```
class DataManager {
    static let shared = DataManager()

    private init() {

    }

    static func set(_ object: String, forKey defaultName: String) { {
        let defaults: UserDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
        defaults.set(object, forKey:defaultName.rawValue)
        defaults.synchronize()
    }

    static func object(forKey key: DataManagerDefaultName) -> String {
        let defaults: UserDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
        return defaults.object(forKey: key) as! String
    }
}
```

Executing:

```
// executing:

// setting the value:
DataManager.set("my value", forKey: .hash)

// getting the value:
let myValue = DataManager.object(forKey: .hash) // "my value"
```

Note that you'd be able to not only set the value by using the enum, also getting it.

Answer (score 1):

I find the most clean approach to be defining an `enum` inside the class, like this:

```
class DataManager {
    enum Key: String {
        case hash
    }

    static let shared = DataManager()

    private init() {

    }

    static func set(_ object: String, forKey defaultName: DataManager.Key) {
        let defaults: UserDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
        defaults.set(object, forKey:defaultName.rawValue)
        defaults.synchronize()
    }

    static func object(forKey key: DataManager.Key) -> String {
        let defaults: UserDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
        return defaults.object(forKey: key.rawValue) as! String
    }
}
```

Usage stays the same as if it were defined outside, since Swift will infer the `DataManager.Key` prefix:

```
DataManager.set("some hash", forKey: .hash)
```